# How to highlight first row of table JQuery on page load ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-highlighting, highlight

My following code works fine if any row is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#currentloc_table tr').click(function(event) {
    $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" input:checkbox")[0].checked = !  ($("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" input:checkbox")[0].checked);
    if($("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" input:checkbox")[0].checked == true)
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    else if($("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" input:checkbox")[0].checked == false)
        $(this).removeClass('selected');    
});
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.selected td {
background: yellow;
}
```

What I need that on page load, first row of this table should get highlighted. How can i do that?

Comment: Is it worked mine...??@Nida Sulheri

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#currentloc_table tr').click(function (event) {
            $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:checkbox")[0].checked = !($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:checkbox")[0].checked);
            if ($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:checkbox")[0].checked == true)
               $(this).addClass('selected');
            else if ($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:checkbox")[0].checked == false)
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    // Add these lines
    var firstTr = $('#currentloc_table tr:first');
    firstTr.addClass('selected');
    firstTr.find("input:checkbox")[0].checked = true;
});
```

working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdHyK/)**

Comment: This is the complete answer. Everyone else left out the checkbox part, probably because it was not in the question.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija I appreciate your detailed reply but i am sorry to say that highlighting is still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this use `.first()` or `:first()` to select the target:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#currentloc_table tr').first().addClass('selected');
   ....
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#currentloc_table tr:first').addClass('selected');
   ....
```

You can though take a look at these:

1. `.eq()` and `:eq()`
2. `nth-child()`
3. `:first-child`

[read documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Or `:first-of-type` selector.

Comment: yup thanks mate just missed that one too although there are several other ways to get this kind of thing (_don't have word for it_).

Comment: Is your table dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the function after load

```
$('#currentloc_table tr:first-child').trigger('click');
```

For this to work you should add this after binding click event with:

```
 #currentloc_table tr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#currentloc_table tr:first"):css('background','yellow');
})
```

or else try with

```
$("#currentloc_table tr").eq(0):css('background','yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code could be improved sligtly:

```
$('#currentloc_table tr').click(function (event) {
    var check = $("input:checkbox", this)[0];
    check.checked = !check.checked;
    $(this)[check.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
});
```

To select the first row:

```
$('#currentloc_table tr:first').click();
```

Comment: thanks for detailed reply. but the problem still persists. It did not highlight first row after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#currentloc_table').find('tr:first').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: It did not work. The first row did not get highlight after page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#currentloc_table tr').first().addClass('selected_f');
  // rest of your stuff ....
```

And css

```
.selected_f {
     background: yellow;
}
```

Your CSS class taking as default for selected class, so its not adding that class , and not able to see the effect

Comment: Its better if you provide JsFiddle